# Can Psd mockup work in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, mockup

I’m new and hoping someone can help out please. I purchased some mockups for my designs not realising the files are psds. I’ve never used photoshop, I use AI but I’m currently on holiday for some time & due to slow internet & limit I will be unable to download photoshop, the psd files basically act like ordinary image in AI (I assume once opened in PS they should be smart objects which allows to place my images in the phone shapes easily??). In the meantime is there a way to do this in illustrator? 
Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to define "work".

.psd documents can be opened or placed inside Illustrator documents. How they operate depends upon the construction of the Photoshop file. It's possible to retain things such as Live Type, Vector shapes, etc when opening a .psd with Illustrator.

However...

Most of the templates I've seen along these lines have beed specially configured for Photoshop with layers and layer masks to allow the user to place images or objects onto the device while retaining the overall shape and appearance of the device itself.

Such as a smart object layer containing layer styles, allowing the user to change the smart object contents but retain all the visual highlights/shadows to make it appear as though everything is on the device. You *will* lose all that in Illustrator.

So with the .psd placed or opened in Illustrator, you won't have any defining masks and there's no access to Photoshop smart object layers directly. You can stack objects on top of the image, but you will need to create your own masks and your own highlights/shadows as desired.